# Disable high DPI scaling for flutter on desktop

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

Is it possible to disable the high dpi scaling for a flutter app?
My layout works well, but when the scale factor is set to something very high the app becomes tiny.

Or is there atleast a way to take the scaling into account?

Comment: I had the exact same problem and came to the conclusion to edit all size numbers or make them responsible. But would be interesting if there is an solution.

Comment: @Thoxh I would like to not change those values because without scaling everything will be very big. A way to at least access the dpi scaling value would be needed.

Comment: @Thoxh I am now using [responsive framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework) which solves the scaling problem by setting `defaultScale: true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am now using the [responsive framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework) package. This solves the scaling problems for me when setting `defaultScale: true`. When adding breakpoints the behavior can be customized.

I am using it in my `MaterialApp.OnGenerateRoute`:

```dart
PageRouteBuilder switchScreen (Widget screen) =>
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
      screen,
      defaultScale: true,
      breakpoints: [
        const ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(450, name: MOBILE),
        const ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
        const ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: TABLET),
        const ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(1200, name: DESKTOP),
        const ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(2460, name: "4K"),
      ],
    ),
    settings: settings,
    transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) =>
      FadeTransition(opacity: a, child: c)
  )
...
```